# Closing a file descriptor I've used with fdopen

Tags: python, file-io, file-descriptor

What, if anything, do I need to do to close a file descriptor I got from `os.open` and subsequently used with `with os.fdopen`? The `OSError` I get from the code below makes me think the answer might be "nothing," but I can't find confirmation in the docs.

```
fd = os.open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/foo"), os.O_WRONLY)
with os.fdopen(fd, "wt") as file:
    pass
os.close(fd) # OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 2 and normally in Python 3 the file is opened with `fdopen` the C standard IO owns the file descriptor. When the file is closed with `fclose` then the underlying descriptor is also closed. Thus the file is closed at the end of the `with` block.

The linux manual on [`fdopen`*(3)*](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) says

> The fdopen() function associates a stream with the existing file
>   descriptor, fd. The mode of the stream (one of the values "r", "r+",
>   "w", "w+", "a", "a+") must be compatible with the mode of the file
>   descriptor. The file position indicator of the new stream is set to
>   that belonging to fd, and the error and end-of-file indicators are
>   cleared. Modes "w" or "w+" do not cause truncation of the file. **The
>   file descriptor is not dup'ed, and will be closed when the stream
>   created by fdopen() is closed.** The result of applying fdopen() to a
>   shared memory object is undefined.

---

In Python 3 [`os.fdopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fdopen) is a wrapper/almost-alias for the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) builtin function:

> `os.fdopen(fd, *args, **kwargs)`
>
> Return an open file object connected to the file descriptor `fd`. This is an alias of the `open()` built-in function and accepts the same arguments. The only difference is that the first argument of `fdopen()` must always be an integer.

And the documentation of `open` documentation has this to say on opening file descriptors:

> `open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)`
>
> Open file and return a corresponding file object. If the file cannot be opened, an OSError is raised.
>
> **file is** either a string or bytes object giving the pathname (absolute
>   or relative to the current working directory) of the file to be opened
>   or **an integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped. *(If a file
>   descriptor is given, it is closed when the returned I/O object is
>   closed, unless closefd is set to False.)***

Thus if you *want* to keep the file descriptor opened when Python file object is closed, you can do

```
fd = os.open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/foo"), os.O_WRONLY)
with os.fdopen(fd, "wt", closefd=False) as file:
    pass

# I/O object dissociated but fd valid
os.close(fd) # no error.
```